# Best practice for reverting a modified Entity within JSF?

Tags: jsf

I'm struggling with how to maintain the state of Entity's within JSF.  Specifically, lets say I want to perform a simple CRUD operation on one.  I bind a bunch of the Entity's attributes to a form, I make some changes in the form, but then I cancel it.  The Entity, in my page's bean on the server, is still modified.  (Let's say that the UI actually submits the form data back because it uses some action listeners to update the form while you are editing it or something).

How do people handle reverting the Entity to its original state?

- Do you always backup/clone your entities before binding them to a form?  This seems like a lot of work, programatically.
- Or Do you always re-get the data from the database when you cancel?  That seems like a waste of a database operation.

Just wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably cloning the entity & then updating on it is a better way.

In this way, you can retain your initial values & can do comparison/validations etc. if required. In some cases displaying end user about the changes being done by him/her; more use cases involve audits etc etc.

Also, going back to database isn't recommended when you already had fetched that entity.

Comment: Right, the only problem with this is having to write a clone operation for every single Entity we use...and we have a lot of them.

Comment: @wfsaxton I think there are few libraries available to clone an object, you try as you have lots of entities; might avoid implementing for each one.